# Repositioning bootstrap card after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

through Bootstrap Studio and a few lines of PHP, I dynamically generate a series of Cards.
I can filter the cards via an input box, but the filtered cards, don't reposition....they do if i change the width of the browser window....is there a way to make them reposition?

I'm posting my code

```
<div style="padding: 20px;border-radius: 20px;" id="card-list">
                    <div class="row" id="myItems" data-masonry="{&quot;percentPosition&quot;: true }" >
                      <?php
                      //creo l'elenco dei campionati che si disputeranno fra oggi e domani
                      foreach ($arr_fed_NS as $key => $value) {
                        $text_camp=str_replace(']','',str_replace('[','',$value));
                        // echo '<br>ecco: '.$text_camp.'<BR>';
                        echo'
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <a href="table.php?camp=['.$text_camp.']"><picture type="" srcset=""><img class="card-img-top p-3" src="'.$arr_camp[$text_camp].'" style="border-radius: 24px; object-fit: cover"></picture></a>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h3 class="fw-bolder card-title" style="text-align: center;--bs-body-font-weight: bold;">'.$text_camp.'</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div><script async="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js" integrity="sha384-GNFwBvfVxBkLMJpYMOABq3c+d3KnQxudP/mGPkzpZSTYykLBNsZEnG2D9G/X/+7D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                </div>
```

```
function prova(){
    const input = document.getElementById('filter').value.toUpperCase();
    const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

    for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
      let title = card[i].querySelector(".card-body h3.card-title");

      if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
        card[i].style.display="";

      }else {
        card[i].style.display="none";
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Welcome! Please remove the excessive leading indentation from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)).

Comment: `card[i].style.display=""` should probably be `card[i].style.display="block"`. Also, what do you mean by "don't reposition?" Please be specific.

Comment: Basically, the cards are arranged according to the media queries, but after filtering, the cards that remain do not take the place of those that disappear, i.e. they are not repositioned, remaining where they were before filtering

Comment: I think I fixed it ...just commented out the script https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js